# Reading multiple CSV file and writting selective variables in new single csv/text file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Sorry for asking this basic question. I have around 200 CSV files some having only 2 rows while some are having 13 rows. Now I need to read all these files and write a separate/another CSV/text file containing only 2 selective rows for all these 200 CSV files.

Through some online resources I wrote the following code,

```
filenames = os.listdir(PATH)
filenames = [file for file in filenames if '.csv' in file]
for file in filenames:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, )
        df['Time1'] = df['Time'].astype(float)
        df['alpha.water1'] = df['alpha.water'].astype(float)
        print(df['Time1'])
```

I need to write a separate csv/txt file which contain only two rows, one containing the variable "time" and other containing the variable "alpha.water". But I am surprised when I print the data, for some files it is showing weird data. Any comments/suggestions will be a great help. The first csv looks like:

```
Time    alpha.water 
0.008   0.01147
```

While the 200th file looks like:
[image]

Any further comments/suggestions will be great help. Thanks again for your consistent help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your csv file? The issue is related to the contents of the files, so we cannot be of help if we don't know what's in the files

Comment: Do you mean rows or columns? `df['Time']` will grab the column 'Time'. You can use `df.loc[]` to get/set the row.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Many thanks for your comment. Actually, I tried to upload the csv files but was unable to do that, could you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: @dlever Yes I need the column value corresponding to the variable "Time". Does that makes sense ? Thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: @RJAdriaansen  Actually I have now added the details of CSV files, any further comments/suggestion ?

Comment: It looks like your `csv` is either tab-separated or separated by multiple spaces. Try `pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')` and `pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True)`. Also, there is no need to convert these columns to `float` as `read_csv` will already parse them as `float`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RJAdriaansen for your comment, as per your comment I re-wrote the read statement using `pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')`, but now when I tried to print the time column using `print(df["Time"])` it is giving me error which says: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(df["Time"])
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc`

Comment: Did you get the same error with `delim_whitespace=True`? Did you check whether the column exists using `df.head()`? Also, you might want to consider moving to python 3, since python 2 is no longer supported.